# How to identify version of XPages Extension Library?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

How can I find out what version of the XPages Extension Library is running on a Domino server?

"tell http osgi ss" lists a lot of different versions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have access to the Domino server you can issue the command

```
tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib
```

The output of the command will show all the deployed versions of ExtLib but only the ones marked as active will be used by the server. This will always be the latest version if multiple versions are deployed.

If you don't have access to the Domino server then you can use an internal utility of ExtLib to return the version number. This sample code could be added to a computed field control to display the version number :

```
var v = com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil.getExtLibVersion();
return "XPages ExtLib version: "+v
```

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib

2012-02-01 16:28:16   Framework is launched.
2012-02-01 16:28:16   id State       Bundle
2012-02-01 16:28:16   10 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   11 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.tooling_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   12 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.sbt_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   13 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   14 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.relational_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   15 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   17 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.feature.source_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   18 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlibx_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   19 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   20 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   21 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.xspprops_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   23 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.tooling.feature.source_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   25 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.source_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   26 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.oauth_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16                Master=33
2012-02-01 16:28:16   28 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.relational.derby_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   29 <<LAZY>>    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.core_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   32 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16   33 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib_8.5.3.20120126-0415
2012-02-01 16:28:16                Fragments=26, 163, 171, 173, 174
2012-02-01 16:28:16   162 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.connections_8.5.2.201102151459NTF
2012-02-01 16:28:16   163 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.connections_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
2012-02-01 16:28:16                Master=33
2012-02-01 16:28:16   164 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_8.5.2.201102151459NTF
2012-02-01 16:28:16   165 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
2012-02-01 16:28:16   166 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_8.5.2.201102151459NTF
2012-02-01 16:28:16   167 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
2012-02-01 16:28:16   168 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_8.5.2.201102151459NTF
2012-02-01 16:28:16   169 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
2012-02-01 16:28:16   170 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.derby_8.5.3.201108271859NTF
2012-02-01 16:28:16   171 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
2012-02-01 16:28:16                Master=33
2012-02-01 16:28:16   172 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.sametime_8.5.2.201102151459NTF
2012-02-01 16:28:16   173 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.sametime_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
2012-02-01 16:28:16                Master=33
2012-02-01 16:28:16   174 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.V853_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
2012-02-01 16:28:16                Master=33
2012-02-01 16:28:16   175 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib_8.5.2.201102151459NTF
2012-02-01 16:28:16   176 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib_8.5.2.201108271859NTF
```