# Runtime error: "Cannot find the library com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library" (browser)

Tags: xpages

I just created my first Xpage application, and I now wanted to port it to a simple mobile application, using the mobile controls in the Xpages Extension Library. Notes/Domino 8.5.3 Upgrade Pack 1 are installed on both client/Designer and server.
The Xpage application works fine in both client and browser.
I created a new Xpage, called "mobileMainPage", and simply add a Single Page Application control to it, save the file and attempt to open it through a browser (Safari first, then IE 9 just to test). In both cases I get the following error message:
*Unexpected runtime error 
The runtime has encountered an unexpected error. 
Exception 
Cannot find the library com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library, required by the application /Contacts.nsf.*

I am opening the database on the server (entering the URL of the .xsp file in the browser). I am not using the preview browser feature of Domino Designer, but is calling the page like a user would.

How do I fix this? I even tried to install Upgrade Pack 1 once more. Still getting the same error message.

Comment: I never got this to work, but I have now upgraded to Notes/Domino 9.0, and will try it there. So I will accept Declan's answer to this question. Thank you everyone for helping me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really sounds like the library is not installed on the server.

type `tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib` on the server console and verify that the plugin is installed, that command should return a list of the extlib plugins and fragments and if they have been correctly resolved or not.

Comment: When I type the above, I do not get anything, just two rows saying 
"framework is launched" and "id State    Bundle".  If I do 'tell http osgi packages' I get this:
02/29/2012 07:28:47 AM    update@../../extlib/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_8.5.3.20111208-0717.jar [152] imports

Any ideas? I reinstalled the server clean with 8.5.3 Upgrade Pack 1, as I had the old ExtLib on it at one time.

Comment: Check out this stackoverflow post for an example of what you should be seeing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098523/how-to-identify-version-of-xpages-extension-library

Answer (score 2):

in your Domino console type:

tell http xsp diag com.ibm.xsp.extlib

also try:

tell http xsp diag com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile

This will tell you whether or not the plugin is resolved. If the plugin is not found it means the plugin is not installed the to correct location (domino/data/domino/workspace/applications/eclipse/plugins).. If a plugin that extlib depends on is not resolved it will show in the console.
Chapter 3 of the XPages Portable Command Guide goes into this in great detail :-)

Let me know the results of the above command

Comment: The first one returns as follows:
[0E74:0002-0DF0] 02/29/2012 10:14:28 PM  update@../../extlib/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.extlib_8.5.3.20111208-0717.jar [157]
[0E74:0002-0DF0] 02/29/2012 10:14:28 PM  No unresolved constraints.

The second one returns:
[0E74:0002-0DF0] 02/29/2012 10:17:12 PM  update@../../extlib/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_8.5.3.20111208-0717.jar [152]
[0E74:0002-0DF0] 02/29/2012 10:17:12 PM  No unresolved constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to tell your app that it should use the extension library. Open the Application Properties and go to the Advanced tab. Here, verify that the 'com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library' is checked.

Comment: The error he's receiving indicates that setting is already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered a similar issue when firing up a new server in a virtual machine (was testing out an issue with different server version). I included notes.ini setting OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES and pointed it to a updatesite database I hastily replicated over from another server.

I am not certain for sure, but once I added my new server to the updatesite and restarted http, it took.